# Spring security token refresh and JWT signature does not match locally computed signature

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have been struggling with token refresh with Spring Boot Security.

Before that I had complete working authentication with JWT, but now when I created this refreshing system it cannot login anymore. Says "JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.". I have tried to solve this problem with different topics found here and from Google.

Now, I can not understand this case, where the error coming from. I crashes on JWT validation method:

JwtUtils.java

```
package com.testapp.springbooot.security.jwt;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;

import com.testapp.springbooot.security.services.UserDetailsImpl;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;

@Component
public class JwtUtils {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

  @Value("${testapp.app.jwtSecret}")
  private String jwtSecret;

  @Value("${testapp.app.jwtExpirationMs}")
  private int jwtExpirationMs;

  public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {

    UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

    return Jwts.builder()
        .setId("" + userPrincipal.getId())
        .setIssuedAt(new Date())
        .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
        .signWith(key(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
        .compact();
  }

  private Key key() {
    return Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512);
  }

  public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key()).build()
               .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
  }

  public String getEmailFromJwtToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key()).build()
            .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
  }

  public Date getExpirationFromJwtToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key()).build()
            .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getExpiration();
  }

  public String getUserIdFromJwtToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key()).build()
            .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getId();
  }

  public boolean isJWTExpired(String authToken) {
    Date expiresAt = getExpirationFromJwtToken(authToken);
    return expiresAt.before(new Date());
  }

  public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
    try {
      Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key()).build().parse(authToken);
      return true;
    } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
      logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
      logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
      logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

and signin authentication controller:

```
@PostMapping("/signin")
  public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
        .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getEmail(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);

    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream().map(item -> item.getAuthority())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    User completeUser = userRepository.findById(userDetails.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException(userDetails.getId(), "user"));

    RefreshToken refreshToken = refreshTokenService.createRefreshToken(userDetails.getId());

    return ResponseEntity
        .ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, refreshToken.getToken(), userDetails.getEmail(), roles, completeUser.getFirstName(), completeUser.getLastName(), completeUser.getHeight(), completeUser.getSex()));
  }
```

I have annoying headache of this error. Just cannot find the solution. Tried few solutions found but not working. Still saying the same error.

Comment: It appears that you are using a different secret key for signing the JWT during token generation (`generateJwtToken`) and validation (`validateJwtToken`). In the `generateJwtToken`, you are using `Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)` to generate a new secret key each time, whereas in the `validateJwtToken`, you are using the `key()`, which generates a new secret key using the same algorithm.
To resolve this issue, you should use the same secret key for both signing and validation. One way to achieve this is to store the secret key as a field in your JwtUtils component and reuse it.

Comment: i just want to warn you, this typ of authentication is not recommended, and that is why it doesnt exist in spring security. You should never hand out JWTs to browsers as it is insecure.

Comment: Thanks @Toerktumlare! Frontend is not even started, just making backend first. When get this all working, I'll need to find the most secure way to handle JWT. Found quite good material here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340275/where-to-save-a-jwt-in-a-browser-based-application-and-how-to-use-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, same key should be used for generating JWT token and validating that same JWT.

It appears that you are using a different secret key for signing the JWT during token generation (`generateJwtToken`) and validation (`validateJwtToken`). In the `generateJwtToken`, you are using `Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)` to generate a new secret key each time, whereas in the `validateJwtToken`, you are using the `key()`, which generates a new secret key using the same algorithm. To resolve this issue, you should use the same secret key for both signing and validation. One way to achieve this is to store the secret key as a field in your JwtUtils component and reuse it.